# Where in the stack exchange network does one ask questions about donations to charity

Tags: discussion

I just asked a question that was clearly not suited for stack overflow, so I figured I'd ask here:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135173/i-want-to-put-up-a-donation-link-to-a-charitable-cause-in-my-site

instead of a helpful advice it got immediately closed and downvoted. **Where** do I ask this? Off topic, I get that and am sorry, but that's all the feedback I received: a "GTFO".

The question's at least semi-programming-related and I need a concrete answer: ways to implement and a reference to charity organizations that accept online donations.

Please help me, guys, I can't think of a more proper place to ask this than in Programmers.

Comment: The stack exchange startup site might help you http://answers.onstartups.com/

Comment: If you are looking to run a charitably funded project, you should look at sites like [IndieGoGo.com](http://www.indiegogo.com/).  They help connect donors from across the world to various charitable causes or independent projects.  In return, people who run projects can give collectible tokens or name recognition to big donors as an offer of gratitude.  They are pretty fair and only take a modest cut of what you are able to bring in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some questions that are off topic *everywhere* on the current Stack Exchange network. We haven't got 100% topic coverage yet (and I don't think we will), and some questions that aren't suited to the Q&A format.

You might get some joy on Webmasters - but check out the site first before posting.

You can also try asking in chat - either [Programmers](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21) or [Stack Overflow](http://chat.stackoverflow.com).

The concrete implementation issue should be on topic on Stack Overflow. However, the request for charity organisations that accept online donations would be one of those questions that doesn't fit the Q&A model.